# How do I set VsCode launch.json for python debugging of specific function among others?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Let's assume my python script has:

```
def func1():
   <body>
def func2():
   <body>
...
def funcN():
   <body>
```

and I would like to set my VsCode debugger to step into funcN

I've looked at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging, but I can only see file to debug (assuming single function I guess) with

```
"program": "${file}",
```

but I can't realize how should it be done at the requested scenario

I tried putting breakpoints and step in like that, but it didn't work -
is it doable? How should I configure the **launch.json** file to enable it?

Comment: `I tried putting breakpoints and step in like that, but it didn't work` - Can you elaborate? When I put a breakpoint on the first line of the function's suite/body, it works for me.

Comment: I put breakpoints at the function def line and also in the body first line, it stopped in the def, but doesn't get/enter into the body

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint at the line where the `funN()` is called. Start debugging and **step into** the function:

[image]

> Reference: [Debug Actions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_debug-actions) and [Python Debug Configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)

Comment: "Start debugging" will run whatever you have currently set in your debugger via launch.json.  Also your example runs the whole file. It does not start the debugging at funN.